# Why isn't Redux dispatching action?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

In my React Native project Redux is not dispatching the cart action to the reducer I logged to console a string to see if reducer is being called but it isn't. The action is being called just not dispatched to the reducer. Everything in App.js looks right and all the imports are correct it's like the action hasn't been passed to the reducer.

Reducer:

```
 import ADD_TO_CART from '../actions/cart'
    
    
    const initalState = {
        items: {},
        totalAmount: 0
    };
    
    export default (state = initalState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ADD_TO_CART:
                const addedProduct = action.product
                const prodPrice = addedProduct.price;
                const prodTitle = addedProduct.title;
    
                console.log('prodPrice')
                let updatedCartItem;
    
                if (state.items[addedProduct.id]) {
                    // already have the item in the cart
                    updatedCartItem = new CartItem(
                        state.items[addedProduct.id].quantity + 1,
                        prodPrice,
                        prodTitle,
                        state.items[addedProduct.id].sum + prodPrice
                    );
                }
                else {
                    updatedCartItem = new CartItem(1, prodPrice, prodTitle, prodPrice)
                }
                return {
                    ...state,
                    items: { ...state.items, [addedProduct.id]: updatedCartItem },
                    totalAmount: state.totalAmount + prodPrice
                }
        }
        return state;
    }
```

Action:

```
    export const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART'
    
    export const addToCart = product => {
        console.log('this is working')
        return { type: ADD_TO_CART, product: product }
    }
```

file that is calling dispatch:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native'
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
    import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons'
    
    import ProductItem from '../../components/shop/ProductItem'
    import * as cartActions from '../../store/actions/cart'
    import HeaderButton from '../../components/UI/HeaderButton'
    
    const ProductsOverviewScreen = props => {
        // products is 
        const products = useSelector(state => state.products.availableProducts);
        const dispatch = useDispatch()
        return (
            <FlatList 
                data={products} 
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                renderItem={itemData => (
                    <ProductItem 
                         image={itemData.item.imageUrl} 
                         title={itemData.item.title}
                         price={itemData.item.price}
                         onViewDetail={() => {
                            props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail', { 
                                productId: itemData.item.id,
                                productTitle: itemData.item.title 
                            })
                        }}
                        onAddToCart={() => {
                            dispatch(cartActions.addToCart(itemData.item))
                        }}
                    /> 
                )}
            />
        )
    }
    
    ProductsOverviewScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
        return {
            headerTitle: 'All Products',
            headerRight: () => 
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item 
                    title='Cart' 
                    iconName={'ios-cart'} onPress={() => {
                        navData.navigation.navigate('Cart')
                    }} 
                />
            </HeaderButtons>
        }
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    })
    
    export default ProductsOverviewScreen;

App.js:
   import React from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import productReducer from './store/reducers/products'
import ShopNavigator from './navigation/ShopNavigator'
import cartReducer from './store/reducers/cart'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  products: productReducer,
  cart: cartReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ShopNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

ShopNavigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'

import ProductsOverviewScreen from '../screens/shop/ProductsOverviewScreen'
import ProductDetailScreen from '../screens/shop/ProductDetailScreen'
import CartScreen from '../screens/shop/CartScreen'
import colors from '../constants/colors'

const ProductsNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    ProductsOverview: ProductsOverviewScreen,
    ProductDetail: ProductDetailScreen,
    Cart: CartScreen
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colors.primary
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white',
    }
})

export default createAppContainer(ProductsNavigator)
```

Comment: What is inside ```<ShopNavigator />```?

Comment: That is referencing the React native stack navigator there is no redux in that

Comment: Please post your ShopNavigator component, it’s quite likely that it did not take in your action function `addToCart` as a prop (even if it’s correctly imported), or it was not passed into `connect`, therefore it won’t execute.

Comment: I am asking to make sure the flow is correct from the provider until the component which dispatch the action

Comment: Ok I added the shop navigator

Comment: How you call ```onAddToCart``` inside ```<ProductItem />```?

Comment: this was custom prop I added

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I had to make the import ADD_TO_CART from '../actions/cart' to
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../actions/cart the brackets show the specific import of the variable I wanted. Without the bracket it couldn't find any default function that action was outputting.